# Return json data from express to ajax post request

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I'm having issues with ajax and response from express. Basically, I'm trying to send an error response to ajax post:

```
// authentication failed
return res.json({
    msg: 'Incorrect OTP...'
});
```

```
$.post({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/verifyOTP',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            phone: phone,
            m: m,
            otp: otp,
            withCredentials: true
        }),
        success: function(err) { // hack to get error msg
            console.log(err);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
```

I've tried the error method with $.post (no luck)...and the success function isn't working either...

I've been at this for 2 days :/

I keep getting redirected to my previous page in my workflow.

One thing to note, is that this current route has query parameters: http://localhost:8080/verifyOTP?phone=8191291382&m=11fe12adb039dd2abfa254291c985c1a9cc860d29c4c970594f086fd75500360.1633875932641. This may be the cause for redirect???

Comment: How are you triggering this?   It sounds like you have either an `<a href=""` or `<button>` - if a button, change to `<button type='button`>` as it sounds like the page is reloading, which will happen with either a link (`<a href="">`) to the same page or a button where the default is `<button type='submit'`

Comment: @freedomn-m I think I managed to fix..see below :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

Changed `onClick` -> `on('click' ...)` and put in `e.preventDefault();`

```
$('#submitOTP').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var otp = document.getElementById('otp').value;
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone').innerText;
    var m = document.getElementById('m').innerText;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/verifyOTP',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            phone: phone,
            m: m,
            otp: otp,
            withCredentials: true
        }),
        success: function(err) { // hack to get error msg
            console.log(err);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
});
```